# UIPrintInteractionController doesn't show paper selection

Tags: ios, printing, airprint

I want to write an app to provide printing to an AirPrint printer (Brother QL-820NWB). The problem is, that if I show the UIPrintInteractionController in the app, the paper selection of the printer is not shown.

If I test the printing with the safari-browser (Print-Option in Safari Share Option), then I can see in the "Printer Options" the paper selection for my AirPrint printer.

Has anybody an idea why I can't see the paper selection in my app but in "safari-printing"?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Until now, no general solution.

Now I'm using the Brother SDK and build my own paper selection.